# Why ElementTree can't parse this XML tag correctly?

Tags: python, html, xml, tags, elementtree

The XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<MINiML
   xmlns="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/info/MINiML"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/info/MINiML http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/info/MINiML.xsd"
   version="0.5.0" >

  <Contributor iid="contrib1">
    <Person><First>ENCODE</First><Last>DCC</Last></Person>
    <Email>encode-help@lists.stanford.edu</Email>
    <Organization>ENCODE DCC</Organization>
    <Address>
      <Line>300 Pasteur Dr</Line>
      <City>Stanford</City>
      <State>CA</State>
      <Zip-Code>94305-5120</Zip-Code>
      <Country>USA</Country>
    </Address>
  </Contributor>
</MINiML>
```

Here is how I use the `ElementTree` in Python:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
tree=ET.parse("the_file_above.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
for c in root:
    print c.tag, c.attrib
```

It returns:

```
{http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/info/MINiML}Contributor {'iid': 'contrib1'}
```

And the value of `c.tag` is `'{http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/info/MINiML}Contributor'`, which I expected to be `Contributor`. I'm not sure how the long url mixed in the tag. Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: That is the XML namespace where this tag is coming from. I'm sure the library has a way to get the local tag name, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This library (like others) tries to encode the namespace used into the tag names.  This is done by prepending the namespace in curly braces.  So this is just a feature you might not be aware of and which might be cumbersome to you.  But it is necessary in case you mix XMLs from various sources with various name spaces in which otherwise tag names would clash.